# sed replace with variable

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I want to replace a line that says `alpha = -pi/...` with the correct calculated value in radians of the angle given ie variable n1

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Angle in degrees : " n1

## Convert angle to radians

printf -v "n2" "%.0f" $(echo | bc | awk "BEGIN {print 180/$n1}")

echo "$n1 Degrees = pi/$n2"

printf -v "n3" "alpha = -pi/$n2;"

echo "${n3}"

cd /home/src/octave_scripts/makemesh_rot


sed  "s/alpha =.*/$n3/" makemesh_rot.m > makemesh_rot.m_temp
```

Ive had a look around and tried a few variations changing `"s/alpha =.*/$n3/"` to `'s/alpha =.*/"$n3"/'` and a few other ways all that does is substitues `alpha = -pi/...` with `$n3`

Comment: As you were already told in a previous thread, this sequence doesn't make any sense: `echo | bc | awk "BEGIN {print 180/$n1}"`.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question to a more precise title, since you are posting with the *bash* tags, which makes people think of *variable* as a bash variable, not a variable assignment in an octave script. Remove all those things that are not necessary to have in your script. In principle you are trying to replace an entire line or variable assignment in a octave file. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this very regularly as follows:

```
sed -i -e "s/alpha = .*/alpha = ${n3}/g" makemesh_rot.m
```

The `-i` parameter replaces things directly in-place, which renders the temporary file obsolete.

Comment: So it really should be `sed -i -e "s/alpha = .*/alpha = -pi\/${n2}/g" makemesh_rot.m` but still i get `sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated address regex`

Comment: Actually that just worked. Thanks